# updated? method in Rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.8.7

I am upgrading a rails3.0 app to rails3.1.10
I have model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account

.....

def some_method
  return unless self.account.updated?
  .......
end

end
```

but `.updated?` method seems to be removed from Rails3.1.10
Is there any alternatives to it?
What I need is to track if parent object was changed

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the method `changed?` which is a part of [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

EDIT:

If you want to track a record change after saving you can try the [TrackIt gem](https://github.com/erez-rabih/trackit) which provides exactly the functionality you would like to have.

Comment: I tried changed? but it seems not to work as expected.
Maybe I have missed something deeper in logic of the app

Comment: How do you expect it to behave?

Comment: I know than changed? work like this
`user = User.first
user.name "name"
user.changed? # => false
user.name = "changed"
user.changed? # => true
user.save
user.changed? # => false`

thanks for help

Comment: Edited my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks.
So the behavior of updated? and changed? are the same. But it is not true in my app.